# here my code and i want to save image url in database i am using laravel my question is how i save image url in database

Tags: laravel

here my code and i want to save image url in database i am using laravel my question is how i save image url in database

public function save(Request $req)
{
if(request()->hasFile('photo')){

```
        $path = base_path() . '/public/user-uploads/employee-docs/';
        $repath = '/public/user-uploads/employee-docs/'.request('project');


        if (!file_exists($path))
        {
            mkdir($path);
        }
    $path = $path.'/'.request('project');
    if (!file_exists($path))
        {
            mkdir($path);
        }

         $name = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d-H-i-s_u');

        $file1 = request()->file('photo');
        if($file1->isValid()) {
            $file1->move($path, $name.'.'.$file1->getClientOriginalExtension());
            $file1_url = $repath.'/'.$name.'.'.$file1->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $photo = new attendance;
        $photo ->user_id=$req->user_id;
        $photo ->image_url=$req->image_url;
            return ['status'=>1, 'data'=>$file1_url];
        } else{
            return ['status'=>0, 'data'=>'Invalid image'];

        }

    } else{
        
        return ['status'=>0, 'data'=>'There is no image'];
        
    }
}
```

Comment: you are not saving the object and using wrong value for image url..do you get any specific error??

Comment: "message": "An unknown error occurred",

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have not saved the object $photo

```php
$photo = new attendance;
$photo->user_id=$req->user_id;
$photo->image_url=$req->image_url;
$photo->save() // add this line
```